# Rename column if it has single quote

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I need to rename column in my oracle database using pl/sql. For example you have table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
    id int,
    "'test1" varchar(80),
    "test2" varchar(80)
);
```

and you need to remove all quotes from it. I wrote anonymous block and there is the problem:

```
...
FOR column_rec IN (SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=table_rec.TABLE_NAME) LOOP
    new_column_name := column_rec.COLUMN_NAME;
    new_column_name := REPLACE(new_column_name, chr(34), '');
    new_column_name := REPLACE(new_column_name, chr(39), '');
...
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'ALTER TABLE '
    || table_rec.TABLE_NAME
    || ' RENAME COLUMN '
    || column_rec.COLUMN_NAME
    || ' TO '
    || new_column_name;
...
```

But if column_rec.COLUMN_NAME has just a single quote in it, this script will fail with exception `ORA-01756`, which means there is no closing quote. How can I avoid this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use double quotes to wrap the columns' names even in your script; for example, this works:

```
alter table test rename column "'test1" to test1
```

Your script could be edited as:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'ALTER TABLE '
    || table_rec.TABLE_NAME
    || ' RENAME COLUMN "' /* open the quote */
    || column_rec.COLUMN_NAME
    || '" TO '            /* and close */
    || new_column_name;
```

Also, notice that in this way all the renamed columns will be upper case; if this is what you need, well done, otherwise you have to wrap with double quotes even the new names:

```
...
|| '" TO "'                /* and close, and reopen */
|| new_column_name || '"'; /* and close again */
```